# how to rename a pdf in ibooks on ipod

Tags: ipod, books

I just downloaded 40+ chapters of a medical reference book onto my ipod touch. They were not available to download as a whole book so I had to download them one at a time. I put them all in a folder in ibooks. Instead of being labelled "chapter 1" or "chapter 2" etc, they are all labelled by the name of the book (that is, they all have the same label). This makes referencing them much harder. I want to be able to find certain chapters quickly. Can I rename these pdfs so they can be easier to reference?   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the PDF directory or folder you have your files, touch the "select" option on the top right. Then touch the name of the file you want to rename and the cursor will appear.  Simply delete the garbled-up iBooks name and type the new file name. Finally, touch the aforementioned "select" option to save it.